# error BC42025 Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I run the code, everything is ok but when I create setup project is raising a warning.

My code :

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim p As Process
    Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "result_of_extensions.log"
    Dim filereader As String = "result_of_extensions.log"



    If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a full path; for example C:/folder", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Label18.Visible = True

        p.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Explorefiles.exe", TextBox1.Text)
    End If
```

In this line raising the warning:  `p.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Explorefiles.exe", TextBox1.Text)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This warning is almost certainly being generated no matter how you build your project. The issue is that in the `Process` class, only `Start()` (with no arguments) is an *instance* method. All other versions of `Start()` are *static/shared* methods. So really, when you say `p.Start(*arguments*)`, you're calling the shared method `Process.Start(*arguments*)`. While this is allowed, it is not quite proper since the method you're calling isn't really tied to any particular instance.

Comment: VBA is to VB.NET as *car* is to *carpet*.  The error mentioned is a compiler error which doesnt have anything to do with setup (other than they often recompile the code)

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Thanks for reply, you mean i have to change the method or i have to use other method to call the program?

Comment: @AlexDotis  Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` and get rid of "p"

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much!!